# Is there a way in Snowflake to handle an XML encoding ISO-8859-1?

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that there is an "encoding" option for the JSON file format type in Snowflake. But how about XML? I found an issue loading an XML file encoded in ISO-8859-1 so I don't know what it's the best approach.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

Comment: You are correct there is no encoding option for XML.  What have you tried so far and were you able to get it to load, perhaps with IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS? If not, then you may have to transform the XML outside of Snowflake with other tools to get it to load properly. UTF8 is the default/standard encoding for Snowflake.

Comment: Thank you @SuzyLockwood that doesn't work. I guess I should transform the XML previously as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that would solve your issue, how ever remember this will replace rather encode

```
IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = TRUE | FALSE
Use : Data loading only
```

Definition
Boolean that specifies whether UTF-8 encoding errors produce error conditions. If set to TRUE, any invalid UTF-8 sequences are silently replaced with Unicode character U+FFFD (i.e. “replacement character”).

Default : FALSE

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-xml

Comment: Thanks for letting me know then parsing externally would only be the option